# One function loads before another one is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, onedrive

I am programming a website with javascript and skydrive API.

this is my code:

```
var clientId = '00000000400FFB5A';
var redirectUri = "http://milmantasimmigration.com/skydrive/test/test.html";

WL.init({
    client_id: clientId,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri
});

WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
WL.Event.subscribe("auth.sessionChange", onSessionChange);

var session;
var companyFolders;
var reportFolders;
var reports;

session = WL.getSession();
if (session) {
    log("You are already signed in!");
    getCompanyFolders();
} else {
    WL.login({
        scope: "wl.signin"
    });
}

function onLogin() {
    var session = WL.getSession();
    if (session) {
        log("You are signed in!");
    }
}

function onLogout() {
    WL.logout();
    log("You are logged out!");
}

function onSessionChange() {
    var session = WL.getSession();
    if (session) {
        log("Your session has changed.");
    }
}

function getCompanyFolders() {
    var getCompanyFoldersDeferred = $.Deferred();

    WL.api({
        path: "/me/skydrive/shared",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(

    function(response) {
        companyFolders = [];
        reportFolders = [];
        reports = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].type == "folder") {
                companyFolders.push(response.data[i]);
                getReportFolders(response.data[i].id + "/files/", companyFolders.length - 1);
            }
        }
        $.when.apply($, companyFolders).done(function() {
            getCompanyFoldersDeferred.resolve();
        });
    }, function(response) {
        log("Cannot get files and folders: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
    });

    return getCompanyFoldersDeferred.promise();
}

function getReportFolders(path, index1) {
    var getReportFoldersDeferred = $.Deferred();
    //var index2 = 0;

    WL.api({
        path: path,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(

    function(response) {
        reportFolders[index1] = [];

        reports[index1] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].type == "folder") {
                reportFolders[index1].push(response.data[i]);
                //index2++;
                getReports(response.data[i].id + "/files/", index1, reportFolders[index1].length - 1);
            }
        }
        $.when.apply($, reportFolders).done(function() {
            getReportFoldersDeferred.resolve();
        });
    }, function(response) {
        log("Cannot get files and folders: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
    });
    return getReportFoldersDeferred.promise();
}

function getReports(path, index1, index2) {
    var getReportsDeferred = $.Deferred();
    //var index3 = 0;

    WL.api({
        path: path,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(

    function(response) {
        reports[index1][index2] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].type == "file") {
                reports[index1][index2].push(response.data[i]);
                //index3++;
            }
        }
        $.when.apply($, reports).done(function() {
            getReportsDeferred.resolve();
        });
    }, function(response) {
        log("Cannot get files and folders: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
    });
    return getReportsDeferred.promise();
}

getCompanyFolders().done(function() {
    showReportsHTML();
});

function showReportsHTML() {
    for (var i = 0; i < companyFolders.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < reportFolders[i].length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < reports[i][j].length; k++) {
                alert(reports[i][j][k].name);
            }
        }
    }
}

function log(x) {
    alert(x);
}
```

these two lines

```
getCompanyFolders();
showReportsHTML();
```

shoulde execute functions one after another after getCompanyFolders() function finishes its job. But showReportsHTML() is executet before getCompanyFolders() fills reports 3D array.

How to launch showReportsHTML() function after getCompanyFolders() is fully done?

Comment: asynchronous calls, got to love them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WL.api()` is asynchronous, so execution continues on to the next function.

You can each function return deferred objects:

```
getCompanyFolders().done(function() {
    showReportsHTML();
});

function getCompanyFolders() {
    var getCompanyDeferred = $.Deferred();

    WL.api({
        path: "/me/skydrive/shared",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
        var deferreds = []
        foreach(item in response) { 
            deferreds.push(getReportFolders());
        }

        $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
            getCompanyDeferred.resolve();
        });

    });

    return getCompanyDeferred.promise();
}
```

This is obviously a simplified example. The structure of `getReportFolders` and `getReports` would look very similar. Let me know if you need me to take the example further.

**Edit in response to your update**

A couple things still. First,

`getCompanyFolders();` should be:

```
getCompanyFolders().done(function() {
    showReportsHTML();
});
```

Second, `$.when()` accepts `deferred` or `promise` objects, which in your case is the return value from your functions.

So in `getCompanyFolders`, your deferred objects are being returned by the calls to `getReportFolders`. Those results are what should be pushed into an array and passed to `$.when`:

```
function getCompanyFolders() {
    var getCompanyFoldersDeferred = $.Deferred();

    WL.api({
        path: "/me/skydrive/shared",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(

    function(response) {
        companyFolders = [];
        reportFolders = [];
        reports = [];
        var deferreds = []; // <------- new array to hold deferred objects
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].type == "folder") {
                companyFolders.push(response.data[i]);
                deferreds.push(getReportFolders(response.data[i].id + "/files/", companyFolders.length - 1)); // <------- hang on to the results from this function
            }
        }
        $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() { // <--- wait on all the deferreds to resolve
            getCompanyFoldersDeferred.resolve();
        });
    }, function(response) {
        log("Cannot get files and folders: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
    });

    return getCompanyFoldersDeferred.promise();
}
```

`getReportsFolders` needs to be changed similarly.

`getReports` doesn't need to wait on anything else to resolve. Once we hit the callback, we're done:

```
function getReports(path, index1, index2) {
    var getReportsDeferred = $.Deferred();
    //var index3 = 0;

    WL.api({
        path: path,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(

    function(response) {
        reports[index1][index2] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].type == "file") {
                reports[index1][index2].push(response.data[i]);
                //index3++;
            }
        }

        getReportsDeferred.resolve();  // <---- all done, nothing else to wait on.

    }, function(response) {
        log("Cannot get files and folders: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
    });
    return getReportsDeferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Well, getCompanyfolders() also calls getReportFolders() and this funcion calls getReports(). After all this sequence I need to call showReportsHtml() to run through all reports[][][] array members and add some DOM elements and text. So I dont think that 2 or 3 method will work. Also, I haven't found information that WL.api returns a promising object.

If I cant do it this way, 
then I am going to add DOM elements in getCompanyFolder(), getReportFolders() and getReports() functions. Do you think this will be a good idea?

Comment: @Rokas Edited to show what I think is a better solution.. didn't think it all the way through the first time.

Comment: Oh, I have remembered that I cant do this way "If I cant do it this way, then I am going to add DOM elements in getCompanyFolder(), getReportFolders() and getReports() functions.".

I need to know somehow when the sequence of getCompanyFolders, getReportFolders, getReports will finish and then call showReportsHTML function..

Comment: Yes, that is what my recent edit does. Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/. Basically, that object is a way for a calling function to be notified when the called function has completed some task. In your case, you will just have a bunch of deferred objects nested three levels deep.

Comment: Thank you for your clean example. It was easy to rewrite 'getReportFolders' and 'getReports' functions. Unfortunately, 'showReportsHTML' function is not called. I have updated my code in primary post. Please review :). Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: @Rokas Edited my post. See especially my comments starting with `// <----`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for brief explanation. I understand all the process now and my code works as it should. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `getCompanyFolders` is calling an asynchronous function. If you want something to happen after this function has finished, you have to provide a callback function:

```
function getCompanyFolders(callback) {
    companyFolders = [];

    WL.api({
        path: "/me/skydrive/shared",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(

    function(response) {
        reportFolders = [];
        reports = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].type == "folder") {
                companyFolders[companyFolders.length] = response.data[i];
                getReportFolders(response.data[i].id + "/files/", companyFolders.length - 1);
            }
        }
        callback();
    }, function(response) {
        log("Cannot get files and folders: " + JSON.stringify(response.error).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
        callback();
    });
}
```

Now you can call `getCompanyFolders` and simply pass `showReportsHTML` as an argument.

```
getCompanyFolders(showReportsHTML);
```